# What physical component performs bootstrapping

Tags: operating-system

I have been studying OS for a while and i know that bootstrap initializes all aspects of the system, but does the CPU perform bootstrap or is it another component?

Comment: The BIOS or UEFI is also used. Read [this OS textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and see [OSDEV](https://www.osdev.org/) and http://linuxfromscratch.org/ BTW, your question is hardware specific and OS specific

Comment: The component reference you are looking for is likely something close to, 'programable ROM.' Maybe, 'BIOS,' or, 'UEFI/EFI.' Firmware is probably called firmware because it exists on read-only hardware. There are probably firmware systems I am not aware of. Off-topic suggestion to an individual in a position to do it .. solder another EEPROM adjacent circuitwise and control which is in charge of booting the rest of the board with a jumper or switch or something.

Comment: Thank you guys!. I will definitely look into the OS textbook for extra information.